# AWS CodePipeline CodeBuild SAM Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I have a PipeLine for Lambda (NodeJS) Auto Deploy from CodeCommit.

My `buildspec.yml`

```
version: 0.1
phases:
 install:
  commands:
    - npm install
    - aws cloudformation package --template-file samTemplate.yaml --s3-bucket codepipeline-551 --output-template-file outputSamTemplate.yaml
artifacts:
  type: zip
  files:
    - samTemplate.yaml
    - outputSamTemplate.yaml
```

My `samTemplate.yaml`

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Description: An AWS Serverless Specification template describing your function.
Resources:
  KashIoTLambda:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: lambda.handler
      Runtime: nodejs8.10
      CodeUri: ./
      Description: ''
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 3
      Role: 'arn:aws:iam::1234:role/abc-backend'
      Events:
        Api1:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: '/{proxy+}'
            Method: OPTIONS
        Api2:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /MyResource
            Method: ANY
      Environment:
        Variables:
          REGION: ap-south-1
```

The policy attached to the role mentioned for `CodeBuild` gives access to All Resources & All S3 commands.

However, I have the following error from build logs

```
[Container] 2019/01/03 13:25:39 Running command npm install
added 122 packages in 3.498s
 [Container] 2019/01/03 13:25:44 Running command aws cloudformation package --template-file samTemplate.yaml --s3-bucket codepipeline-551 --output-template-file outputSamTemplate.yaml
 Unable to upload artifact ./ referenced by CodeUri parameter of ABCLambda resource.
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
 [Container] 2019/01/03 13:25:46 Command did not exit successfully aws cloudformation package --template-file samTemplate.yaml --s3-bucket codepipeline-551 --output-template-file outputSamTemplate.yaml exit status 255
[Container] 2019/01/03 13:25:46 Phase complete: INSTALL Success: false
[Container] 2019/01/03 13:25:46 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: aws cloudformation package --template-file samTemplate.yaml --s3-bucket codepipeline-551 --output-template-file outputSamTemplate.yaml. Reason: exit status 255
```

Comment: did you use sam package command first sam package \
    --template-file template.yaml \
    --output-template-file packaged.yaml \
    --s3-bucket REPLACE_THIS_WITH_YOUR_S3_BUCKET_NAME

Comment: https://github.com/varnitgoyal95/IT-Academy-/tree/master/lambda/It-Academy-Lambda refer to readme file

Comment: @varnit as you can see from the logs, the command executed is `aws cloudformation package --template-file samTemplate.yaml --s3-bucket codepipeline-551 --output-template-file outputSamTemplate.yaml`

Comment: its has nothing to do with codebuild you must have  some user set in ~/.awsconfig/credential file and that user must have permission to access your s3 bucket so before you call cloud formation package command you need to place this file in your enviroment with suitable aws credentials

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/config-vars.html

Comment: did the above solution work ?

Comment: @varnit the subjected command is executed by `CodeBuild` not some normal user and the same is mentioned in the problem and can be seen in `buildspec.yml` file.

Comment: Code build use some linux based machine to run your build, and in that linux machine you are using a tool known as aws cli which needs that credential file

Answer (score 2):

Check the policies/permissions on the bucket itself.

[image: S3 Bucket Policy]

If you were like me, you may have selected the `default location` option as the artifact store in the pipeline settings when you first set it up. In which case, there may be policies on the S3 bucket itself blocking access.

[image: AWS Pipeline Settings]

For me, once I removed the bucket policy the `unable to upload artifact` error was resolved and my build process went on to complete successfully.

I hope this helps you.